# Confusion about store_id in Magento 2 database

Tags: magento

I'm running Magento 2.1 and migrated data from a Magento 1.9.x install. Everything went well.

My Magento 2.1 installation has a secondary store (the default store is not really used), and the values in the "store" database table look like this:

```
store_id = 0, code = admin, website_id = 0
store_id = 1, code = default, website_id = 1
store_id = 4, code = mysecondstore_english, website_id = 3
```

And the values in the "store_website" database table look like this:

```
website_id = 0, code = admin, name = "Admin"
website_id = 1, code = base, name = "Main Website"
website_id = 3, code = mysecondstore, name = "My Second Store"
```

I went through all of the items in my catalog and made various changes to standardize things, beef up the SEO, and other little tweaks. When editing the items, in the "Product in Websites" section I had two checkboxes: Main Website and My Second Store. By default, the Main Website box was checked so I unchecked that and checked My Second Store.

Basically what this did was create duplicate entries in many of the "catalog_product_entity_xxxxxxxxx" database attribute tables with a store_id of 4, in addition to the existing entries with a store_id of 0.

Now when I edit an item, the changes don't show up on the store because by default it will edit the store_id = 0 database attributes. I have to make the changes manually in the database.

What I want to do is get rid of the duplicate entries, but after doing some testing I'm a bit confused as to which store_id should be used and exactly which tables I would need to change (aside from the "catalog_product_entity_xxxxxxxx" attribute tables). I would have thought that store_id = 4 would be the one to go with, but then the item seems to disappear from the store.

I sure would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest install magento 2 again without errors. This is the easiest way.